# Cannot access Stack Overflow, redirected to the promotions page

Tags: bug

Recently, I tried googling a question and came across a Stack Overflow question:

[image: Google result]

So far so good. I clicked on the link, but got redirected to the  [promotions page](http://stackpromos.com/promos). I also tried to access it via web browser navigation bar, but I got redirected again. I can access any other sites though. How can I fix this?

Quick update:

### <s>This issue has been resolved, however, there is now another one</s>

So I could access stackoverflow, and I can access it right now. However, sometimes, and I especially noticed that about 10 minutes ago, when I visit, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. I cannot reproduce this to make a screenshot, it just appears randomly, and I don't think this is happening for all users (at once, alteast)?

## This issue is completely resolved.

For a while now, neither I received any 502 errors, nor I get redirected.

<s>*It has begun.*</s>

Yes, I am getting the error again. I cannot access stackoverflow, I get redirected to the stackpromos archive. This issue persists.

### Stack Overflow seems moody.

Sometimes I get redirected, sometimes it works fine. It's hard to reproduce and/or produce again, it's based on (bad) luck. A few people have the same problem, none of them either can explain how to reproduce.

I don't expect this to be fixed (or atleast any time soon), because it could be caused by anything (this including it's only on my side). Still keeping this post for archive purposes, I guess.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. what web-broswer are you using?

Comment: Neither could I.

Comment: Cannot repro using Firefox 50.1.0

Comment: Is it possible that OP is shown promos as he has less points?

Comment: tell me your repo ?

Comment: Using firefox, am not on that browser right now though. On this other computer, I can access stackoverflow. I'll try again when I'm home. @leaf

Comment: Maybe is google's cache

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340371/73226 and  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289055/stack-overflow-is-redirecting-to-stackpromos

Comment: Both of those were written **after** my question. If you're implying this is a duplicate, then the questions you specified are actually the duplicates. @MartinSmith

Comment: Why are you getting all het up about some implication that was never made?! I posted two links to people with the same issue.

Comment: @MartinSmith "**If** you're implying". I never put my assumption into stone.

Comment: I'll repeat what I posted in a duplicate a few weeks ago: Can you add HTTP request and response headers to your question? Might help in identifying who or what is causing the redirect.

Comment: I have the same problem.