# Why is Stack Overflow redirecting to stackpromos.com in Chrome?

Tags: bug, google-chrome

I am unable to use Stack Overflow in Chrome. Whatever I do, it redirects to stackpromos.com.

I can't get rid of this behaviour... Currently I have to use the Edge browser for accessing Stack Overflow. Other browsers are fine...

How can I fix this?

Comment: No problems with chrome for me.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/welcome-to-the-internet-of-compromised-things/

Comment: Related from a week ago, but no longer reproducible by the OP: [Cannot access Stack Overflow, redirected to the promotions page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339905/cannot-access-stack-overflow-redirected-to-the-promotions-page)

Comment: Can you add HTTP request and response headers to your question? Might help in identifying who or what is causing the redirect.

Comment: let me analyze this request/respone..

Comment: Someone else with the same issue http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289055/145673

Comment: @Braiam no. it is a site affiliated to SE. See ^

Comment: @PatrickHofman no what?

Comment: You like to the compromised network equipement post on Jeffs blog. That doesn't seem to be the case here. @Braiam

Comment: This is fixed for me now..I cleared Chrome all caches..And i was accessing it in a different network that time when i was facing the issue.. But now i am back to my office premises and the issue seems not exists.

Comment: How long have you been visiting stack exchange? Could you have had a cached JS file from Winterrbash 2012 still on your computer?

Comment: I am a recent user .Just being one month...